# Subroutine to fill in values in a range?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've been trying to write a subroutine to find the first and last instances of a value in a row and fill the middle with the same value. However, I have trouble getting to work. I think the problem is with my range.find method to find the last instance. Can someone help me identify the error?

```
Sub ChangeBetween()
    Dim FirstCell As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim SearchTerm As String
    Dim ChangeRange As Range
    Dim ChangeCell As Range

    'Define search term
    SearchTerm = Range("A1").Value

    'Find beginning and end of replacement range
    Set FirstCell = Range("B2:I2").Find( _
        What:=SearchTerm, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Set LastCell = Range("B2:I2").Find( _
        What:=SeartTerm, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    'Set replacement range
    Set ChangeRange = Range(FirstCell, LastCell)

    'Replace in range
    For Each ChangeCell In ChangeRange
        ChangeCell.Value = SearchTerm
    Next ChangeCell
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `SeartTerm` ?

Comment: `Option Explicit` is your best friend.

Answer (score 3):

I picked up a couple of (what I believe to be) logic holes by specifying the *After:=* parameter of the [.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

```
Option Explicit   'see footnote ¹

Sub ChangeBetween()
    Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range, searchTerm As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")

        'Define search term
        searchTerm = .Range("A1").Value

        'Find beginning and end of replacement range
        With .Range("B2:I2")
            'make sure there is at least one SearchTerm
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells, searchTerm)) Then
                Set firstCell = .Find(What:=searchTerm, _
                                      After:=.Cells(.Columns.Count), _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                Set lastCell = .Find(What:=searchTerm, _
                                     After:=.Cells(1), _
                                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                     LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                     SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                .Parent.Range(firstCell, lastCell) = searchTerm
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

---

¹ <sub>Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This 
will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable 
declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is 
widely considered 'best practice'.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Quoting you

```
Set LastCell = Range("B2:I2").Find( _
    What:=SeartTerm, _ 'this is a typo your variable is SearchTerm
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
```

If I may, why to loop thorugh each cell from final and first?

```
'Replace in range
For Each ChangeCell In ChangeRange
    ChangeCell.Value = SearchTerm
Next ChangeCell
```

Try:

```
ChangeRange.Value = SearchTerm
```